# typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName returning null

Tags: c#, reflection

I've been working with some code that I needed to add a module too and I thought I had everything set up correctly but this last bit has got me stumped.

It seems relatively simple, I'm passing in a type to a Generic Method

```
var name typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

So that I can then do this

```
var type = Type.GetType(name);
```

however it's throwing an exception at that last line with `name` being `null`

I've been reading around type reflection I know that `GetType` expects the fully qualified assembly name but I don't understand why it's coming back as null.

Does it mean I'm doing something fundamentally wrong with my code as i assumed that `AssemblyQualifiedName` is emitted from a type as it knows how it's been referenced?

Comment: Can u try typeof(T).AssemblyFullName and see what you get?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well `AssemblyQualifiedName` *can* return null:

> The assembly-qualified name of the Type, which includes the name of the assembly from which the Type was loaded, or null if the current instance represents a generic type parameter.

It doesn't *look* like it should actually represent a generic type parameter if you're really just using `typeof(T)` - unless the generic method is being called via reflection in some bizarre way.

Why are you trying to use `Type.GetType` though? It sounds like all you need is

```
var type = typeof(T);
```

... wouldn't that do exactly what you want? Why go via the name of the type?

Comment: You are correct, in my particular instance `typeof(T)` works sufficiently. However I can't change it to such due to other dependent code and I've found out why my `AssemblyQualifiedName` was `Null` due to missing Post Build Events in my particular project.